# Sort Datagridview with datasource a list

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a Datagridview (dataGridView1) and the datasource is a list (Bets). I'd like to order it by a column value Ascending (odd1). How Could I do it?

**EDIT:** Maybe I should order list before fill datagridview? any suggestion?

**EDIT2:** I got the solution, but numbers are in a wrong progress. Check pic:

[image]

After 1.99 I'd like to have 2.00 instea of 10.57. How Can I do it?

**EDIT3:**  This is a piece of my class:

public string odd1
    {
        get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[0] : "error"; }
        set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[0] = value; }
    }

```
public string oddX
{
    get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[1] : "error"; }
    set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[1] = value; }
}

public string odd2
{
    get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[2] : "error"; }
    set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[2] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I usually tack this on to all my data grid views its an extra line and gives you some really nice base functionality http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup

Comment: I see, I'll check it, thanks. Anyway I hope someone can suggest me a solution here :) Thanks again

Comment: Also if you're just trying to order it before it goes into the grid just order the list by that field before assigning it as the data source

Comment: Yes, but I don't know to do it when datasource is a list. With a database is more simple but I don't need to use it, so I am trying to find a solution for order this list before to go into datagridview

Comment: You compare strings, they show correctly in the datagrid. You have to compare the strings as double/float.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Linq before setting the gridView's datasource:

**Edit:** Since the type of odd1 is string, you need to convert it to a number to get the desired results. Since not all the numbers are valid, you need to do some checking in order to get the desired result.

```
list = list.OrderBy(x=> ConvertFromString(x.odd1)).ToList();
```

define a method:

```
private decimal ConvertFromString(string str)
{
    decimal val = decimal.MaxValue;

    if (decimal.TryParse(str, out val))
        return val;
    else
        return decimal.MaxValue;
}
```

Or in-place sorting without creating a new list:

```
list.Sort((x, y) =>  (int)(Decimal.Parse(x.odd1) -  Decimal.Parse(y.odd1)));
```

Comment: It's working, thanks, but there's a little problem. Check my edit2 in my question, please

Comment: @Marci this is because the type of odd1 is string and not decimal. Check the edited answer.

Comment: I got this error: Input string was not in correct format

Comment: @Marci do you have null values or values that are not numbers ?

Comment: I edit my question with a piece of my class about odd1, oddx and odd2. They have just numbers

Comment: @Marci No. Not just numbers, they might have the value "error"

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot! I gave you the point. You really deserve it :) Thanks again!